# How to instantiate cubes at every given positions

Tags: unity

I have a list of coordinates in 3D (XYZ)

> list = {{226.29, 485.28, 345.396}, {298.292, 108.226, 551.422},
> {452.987, 164.874, 416.242}, {562.8, 29.4951, 297.651},{-610.087, -99.9056, -156.377},
> {470.804, 12.3284, 428.671}, {590.609, 197.615, -137.146}}

I want to instantiate cubes at every given positions,
how to define given list correctly in C# and use it as a vector3 ?

I tried something like that..

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(list[i]), Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of that list? It's good that you tried something before asking questions on the Internet, but... what happened when you tried that? Do you get an error? What error? Or don't you get an error but it doesn't do what you expect it to do when it runs? What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think should be ok to have a better list structure using List.

If your input is JSON Object, you can use SimpleJson.cs (search on google) to parse the data into a list.

And your coordinates would be:

```
List<Vector3> coordinates = new List<Vector3>() {
    new Vector3(  226.29f,   485.28f,  345.396f), 
    new Vector3( 298.292f,  108.226f,  551.422f), 
    new Vector3( 452.987f,  164.874f,  416.242f), 
    new Vector3(   562.8f,  29.4951f,  297.651f),
    new Vector3(-610.087f, -99.9056f, -156.377f), 
    new Vector3( 470.804f,  12.3284f,  428.671f), 
    new Vector3( 590.609f,  197.615f, -137.146f)
}
```

Then you can instantiate your prefab in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Count; i++)
{
    GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab, coordinates[i], Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Unity's built-in JsonUtility can also handle the conversion.